# Running xjc command for Java 11-works in git bash but not cygwin

Tags: cygwin, git-bash, java-11, xjc

Interesting issue. I'm working on a Java 11 upgrade and ran into a problem running XJC locally. As XJC is no longer part of the JDK I've downloaded our own XJC and the needed jaxb libraries. However, when I run it locally via Cygwin it errors stating that it 'Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade'. After some debugging I pulled out the command being run which produces the error, but with a minor change it works in Git Bash. I'm trying to figure out why it works in Git Bash but not Cygwin (in Windows, as it works on my Linux VM), to maybe gain some insight into what to fix.

1. XJC works successfully on Linux VM (so I know the script is valid)
2. Command (listed below) works with Git Bash on Windows 10 with Java 11
3. Commands (listed further below) FAIL in Cygwin on Windows 10 with Java 11

**Working Git command**

- /c/Programs/Amazon_Corretto/jdk11.0.5_10/bin/java -cp /c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-impl.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.activation.jar com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade -xmlschema /c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code/filename.xsd -d /c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code

**Failed attempts with Cygwin**

- /cygdrive/c/Programs/Amazon_Corretto/jdk11.0.5_10/bin/java -cp /c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-impl.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.activation.jar com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade -xmlschema /c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code/filename.xsd -d /c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code
- /cygdrive/c/Programs/Amazon_Corretto/jdk11.0.5_10/bin/java -cp /cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar:/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-impl.jar:/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.activation.jar com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade -xmlschema /cygdrive/c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code/filename.xsd -d /cygdrive/c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code
- /cygdrive/c/Programs/Amazon_Corretto/jdk11.0.5_10/bin/java -cp /c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-impl.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/lib/jakarta.activation.jar com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade -xmlschema /cygdrive/c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code/filename.xsd -d /cygdrive/c/Development/Project_Folder/path/to/some/code

Comment: I've been continuing to dig into it. The below command 'works' in cygwin but throws an exception.

Command: java -cp `cygpath -w "/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/jaxb-xjc.jar;/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar;/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/jaxb-impl.jar;/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/jaxb-jxc.jar;/cygdrive/c/Programs/jaxb-ri/jakarta.activation.jar"` com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ClassLoaderBuilder.createProtectiveClassLoader(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:45)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade.main(XJCFacade.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.jav

Comment: Have you tried using Linux Subsystem for Windows instead of cygwin?

Comment: I have not. At this time the directive is to maintain our Windows build process using Cygwin. It's possible somewhere down the line they may be open to utilizing gitbash, but at this time I'm stuck with Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

So I have identified the issue being the pathing format.

After alot of trial and error and some brainstorming I figured out the path for the jar files must be in Windows format with a semi-colon delimiter. Somehow during my trials I ended up using a Windows path with ':' delimiter, and later when I correctly used both Windows format and semi-colon delimiter I was using the 'cygpath -w' which is not needed.

So

```
"java -cp "C:\Program File\Path\jaxb-xjc.jar;C:\Program File\Path\jaxb-impl.jar..." com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade.
```